# Regex problem with recognizing alphanumericals

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to build a regex which filters alphanumerical strings. That means something like "12ab" or "ab12" or "a12b". I must not match with single chars or numbers. My attempt was '[0-9a-zA-Z]+'. But this didn t work. For me it is a problem to say "the string starts with a character or a number ..."

Here some examples.

to be recognized:
"aab2" "23ab" "a1" "a2acd"

not to be recognized:
"a" "aads" "1" "232323" "." "+" "sas+"

Greetings,
Haniball

Comment: Could you post some examples of strings that should have been recognized but were not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)|([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+)[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```